# Telegraf bot action multiply

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram, telegraf.js

Tell me please if it is possible to track multiple actions in one

```
bot.action(MULTIPLE ACTIONS, (ctx) => {
    ctx.reply(ctx.callbackQuery.data)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looking the the [Telegraf (bot) Methods](https://telegraf.js.org/classes/Telegraf-1.html#action), we see the first parameter of the `action` method defined as follows:

> action(triggers: Triggers, ...fns: MatchedMiddleware<C, "callback_query">): Telegraf
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - ...
> - triggers: `Triggers<C>`

The plural indicates that you can pass a list of `Triggers`.

---

So you code becomes something like:

```
bot.action(['action1', 'action2'], (ctx) => {
    // Do something
});
```